# Installing Maven library using SBT

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I am new to SBT and do not have prior experience with Maven.
I am trying to add the dependency [JWPL](http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/) to my project. I looked at [their developer setup page](http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/wiki/DeveloperSetup) and found the example of what one would add to a Maven setup file to download the project:

From the link:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia.api</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Which I translated to by `build.sbt` file like so:

```
addSbtPlugin("de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia" % "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia.api" % "0.9.2")
```

However, in `sbt`, when I run update I get:

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/home/me/scala/wikifun/}wikifun...
[info] Resolving de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia#de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia;0.9.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia#de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia;0.9.2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/me/.ivy2/local/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.9.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/wikipedia/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia_2.10_0.13/0.9.2/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia-0.9.2.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia#de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia;0.9.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia:0.9.2 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia#de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia;0.9.2: not found
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Nov 20, 2013 11:23:19 AM
```

In addition to the problem at hand, any help understanding as to what is going during the build process would be appreciated so I could solve the problem on my own in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your build file:

```
libraryDependencies += "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia" % "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia.api" % "0.9.2"
```

The method you used (addSbtPlugin) is (as the name implies) for adding plugins to SBT (and should anyway go in the plugins .sbt file).

See also http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html#adding-library-dependencies